What is the frequency of each damage type dealt by published monsters?
There are lots of reasons to want to know how likely PCs are to face each of the 13 damage types.
In particular, a common homebrew tactic at one of the tables I play at is to take an established (published/playtested) subclass/spell/item and to tweak it. We do this a lot when trying to fit a character concept, for example a "Druid of Winter," into the existing options.
For a Druid of Winter, we might start with the Wildfire subclass but we change the fluff and all the fire damage to cold damage (and probably swap out a few of the spells).
Swapping one damage resistance or immunity for another is a simple change, but it's hard to evaluate how balanced or unbalanced a change like this might be without having a rough estimate of how common a damage type is.
Obviously damage type frequency can vary a lot depending on the campaign. To the extent that this question can be answered precisely, I would assume that all monsters at a given CR are equally likely to appear.

@ValleyLad Derp, you're right. Leaving it as related then: What are the most and least-resisted damage types?

I assume this is about damage output of enemies rather than resistance, so have reopened it. The op already clarified it isn't a duplicate of the linked question.

I voted to close this as opinion based, and it got negated by a pretty obviously invalid duplicate closure. This is just an opinion poll that is only answerable with personal anecdotes, so it is not a good fit for this stack.

Or maybe I’ve misunderstood, are you just asking what is the frequency of each damage type by CR of all published monsters? Because that’s totally objective, but quite different from the title question.

@ThomasMarkov Correct—though I completely disagree that the title question is opinion-based; it's just hard. Someone could monitor a large sample of actual D&D tables and produce an objective distribution of damage types that a typical player encountered—it wouldn't be opinion-based at all, just difficult to do. Regardless, I'm not asking for that, just for the distribution implied by the monster manual/published sources.

@nben Since it isn’t your question, we don’t have to discuss it further. I’ll take a shot at updating the title.

@ThomasMarkov This title works for me!

I took the liberty to break down the body into multiple paragraphs and changed a few sentences to hopefully make the whole thing easier to read and digest. Feel free to revert my edit if you feel it is too much.

@nben are you including bludgeoning, piercing and slashing in this question?

Do you really want to narrow this, as the title of your question now reads, to just the damage dealt by "monsters"? Players also face NPC's hitting them with spells and magic items, which I think would be just as relevant to your use case.

I went to an LLM and got an answer, but frankly felt yucky doing it and posting it here.
You are welcome to do it on your own. Prompt was "Compile a table listing the number of monsters in the D&D 5e Monster Manual that have vulnerabilities, resistances, and immunities to each damage type:

@senmurv Yes! I'm also interested in magical versions of each.

@ValleyLad I would consider that a separate question; the space of possible NPCs is not nicely contained by a manual.

@ΣofeDπ That prompt does not engage with this question, which is not about monster vulnerabilities, resistances, or immunities. Beyond that, if you use an LLM, you'll need to verify every entry in the table. (With a human I might randomly verify some, but with an LLM, verifying a random sample doesn't really change my confidence in the rest of the numbers.)

I disagree. The question asked about swapping damage types on a spell, so information about damage resistances is what this person (you?) should actually be interested in for the purposes of balance.

@ΣofeDπ I am the question asker, and that is not what I am asking. The question mentions changing damage type of a spell as an example of tweaking a subclass, but it asks, "What is the frequency of each damage type dealt by published monsters?"

"Balance" is a subjective a term. My advice is to be content with a fuzzy answer.
The prompt "produce table listing the number of monsters in the D&D 5e Monster Manual that deal each damage type" yielded a reasonable answer. If you want to get fancy, you could have it also factor in the amount of damage dealt.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi @nben  Why is the CR relevant in your question? It seems to me that it would make a potential answer monumentally time consuming. I mean, it's whet my curiosity, but I'm not sure how helpful an answer would be. The DMs' campaigns will vary so a Druid of Winter would be may be advantaged in one setting and not in another. I mean, you could answer it yourself (and get a badge) ;)

@Senmurv My thinking is that 90% of campaigns/characters only go up to level 10 or 15, and it should be easy to take that into consideration. If monsters that are CR 15 or greater, for example, do tons of force damage but monsters below do not, that is clearly relevant for balance decisions about force resistance. Obviously there are lots of other parameters we could split the data on, this one just seems like the most clearly useful (whereas other parameters like monster type are less clearly useful). I do plan to answer this myself when I get a minute to do some counting ;-)
